# GUID API key generation from SQL Server 2008 R2 and SQL Azure for WCF communication

Tags: wcf, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, guid, azure-sql-database

I have table that describes association of two other business models.

Example:

```
Construction Table - available constructions |
Reader Table - available readers |
ReaderPlacement Table - reader assigned to specific construction for specific time.
```

According to my requirements `ReaderPlacement` table must contains `ApiKey`, for me best match is unique `GUID` used later on for WCF communication.

I am planning to write something like this:

```
ApiKey CHAR(36) NOT NULL DEFAULT NewSequentialId()
```

Is it the right solution? I read that `NewSequentialId()` is better than `NewId()` and should be unique.

Does db engine will protect my column to be unique when I use `NewSequentialId()` or I have to add any constraint and additional checks ?

It must be also valid with SQL Azure.

Cheers,
Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just by defining a default of `newsequentialid()`, there is **no guarantee** that you won't have duplicates. Yes - the values generated by SQL Server will have an extremely high likelihood of being unique. But that default constraint doesn't prevent you from inserting explicit values - and those could possibly collide with existing values.

If your column `ApiKey` needs to be unique at all times, you must add a unique constraint

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.ReaderPlacement
ADD CONSTRAINT UC_ReaderPlacement_ApiKey UNIQUE(ApiKey)
```

With this unique constraint in place (which should definitely also work on SQL Azure), then SQL Server will prevent any duplicates from being inserted - any transaction attemting to do so will be terminated with an error message.

Comment: This will work, however I had to change data type from `char(36)` to `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`, otherwise I had Sql Exception during deploy, finally: `ApiKey UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL DEFAULT NewSequentialId()`

Comment: I tested this on SQL Azure and **NewSequentialId() is not supported**... When I figure out something I will let you know... :'(